# Launching the app does not track changes when using golem framework

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I have just stumbled upon **golem** and had a very good experience using it so far. The documentation is also excellent.

My only issue is regarding running the app / launching it (not deployment).
I usually have the app instance running in a browser on one monitor, make changes in my code on another monitor, and simply refresh the browser page every time to update it. That works for everything, even css file modifications.

There is also the built-in 'Run App' button in RStudio which is quite handy.

This time with golem, I have to manually enter `golem::run_dev()` every time.
Using the .Global_Env `run_app()` that is in the *run_app.R* file refreshes the instance but does not update according to my changes in my code, and neither does refreshing the browser. The RStudio Run App also is not available.

So in short, the usual way of refreshing does not track changes.
Not only that, but running `golem::run_dev()` also detaches golem from the active library so I can't just use the shorter the following time `run_dev()`.

How should one go about having responsive updates to the app instance using golem?

I get that most of you on here can just code for a good half-hour knowing how the app will respond then launch it, but for me, I do need to play around quite a bit and go back and forth between code and app.

Kindly let me know, I am curious to know more about the golem workflow.

Comment: do you have the same issue by sourcing the /dev/run_dev.R script ?

Comment: @VincentGuyader it sent me into an infinite loop. I tried using source("dev/run_dev.R") just before with_golem_options(...) in the run_app() function, but that sent me into a loop.

Comment: without source code, it's hard to help if you can share it to me I will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually restart my app every 2 minutes using `golem::run_dev()`, which has always been working and display the changes. I suppose your issue here is with retyping the command every time?

Are you aware of the RStudio addin that can be mapped to a keyboard shortcut?

[image]

[image]

So here is my workflow:

- Code
- Shift + R
- Code change
- Escape to stop the app
- Shift + R
- etc...

[Edit] The shift + R was just an example for the sake of clarity, I'm actually using Cmd + R / Cmd + D (Run Dev)

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea we could do this. I will follow your workflow! On a side note, do you know how to prevent run_dev() from opening a new browser tab each time? I am porting run_app() to 8000 already.